# Massive delete (2 joins required) with no partitionning

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join, sql-delete

I'm experiencing some infinite loop for my delete. I tried many way to deal with this problem but still take too much time. I will try to be clear as possible.

I have 4 implicated table in this problem.

The deletion is done depending of the pool_id given

```
Table 1 contain the pool_id
Table 2 the ticket_id foreign join ticket_pool_id with the pool_id
Table 3 ticket_child_id foreign join ticket_id with the ticket_id
Table 4 ticket_grand_child_id foreign ticket_child_id join with the ticket_child_id

Concerned count for each
table 1---->1
table 2---->1 200 000
table 3---->6 300 000
table 4---->6 300 000
```

So in fact it`s 6.3M+6.3M+1.2M+1 row to be deleted

Here`s the constraint :

- No partitioning
- Oracle version 9
- Online all the time so no downtime neither CTAS
- We cannot use cascade constraint
- The normalization is very important

Here`s what I tried:

- Bulk delete
- Delete with statement (In and Exists clause)
- temp table for each level and 1 level join
- procedure and commit each 20k

None of those worked in a decent time frame like less then one hour. The fact that we cannot base a delete on one of the column value is not helping. Is there a way?

Comment: What's wrong with it taking an hour? Is this something you're trying to do routinely?

Comment: Agreed.  Asumming that you're trying to delete records from `table_4` based off the single record in `table_1`, I'd expect this to take a while (a _long_ while, even with the proper indicies).  Please note that adding additional criteria to your `WHERE` clauses _may_ speed up the delete, if the optimizer can use a different/additional index - for example, if you already know that all rows have a (recorded) creation date before some arbitrary value, or has text that starts with an "A", or whatever.  And you _may_ not need commitment control here...

Comment: How big are the tables? ie. is 6.3M the bulk of the records or a small portion?

Comment: Is the restricting condition solely based on table1 ?

Comment: Thank to all of you for contributing!

Apparently there`s not much to do to improve performance, because of the fact that I need an Id from the first table. 

The best way I found is to do it by chunk with bulk collect and commit every 20k so that if its blows up my Oracle process I could just restart the procedure and resume all instead of redoing the whole thing.
If only I coud use partition :P

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to delete joining the tables the complexity may become cubical or even worse. With tables with many records this will become a performance killer. You can try to output a list of values for deletion from the first table in a temporary table, then use another one to select the IDs for deletion from the second table and so on. I suppose having proper indexes will keep the complexity quadratic and will complete the task in normal porion of time. Good luck

Comment: Did you try disabling the foreign key constraints before the delete operation and enable them again after it. It sometimes work...